# water line leak - major problem

Tags: plumbing, walkway

had a water link leak under a concrete slab walkway to the front porch.  Had to have the walkway taken up and the pipe coming from the house may be a big problem.   Plumber repaired and sleeved however I don't know what to do about a walkway being built in the same area and really concerned about the pipe from the house and what future issues I may have.   So my questions are - any idea what to do for a walkway - and how bad does this situation look for having future problems.   Please note the concrete slab walkway was 10" thick at the back which was over the pipe area.  Photo attached  - the house constructed late around late 96-97.   Any advice/input will be greatly appreciated and if I am in the wrong area to ask this question - please let me know.  Thanks in advance

[!water line i[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QAGc.png)mage description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idwC3.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idwC3.png)

Comment: This is the right area to ask, plumbing under a slab can be a big $ cost on older homes. If your plumber sleeved the pipes that can help but after replacing high quality copper on slabs with flat roofs common in the 60’s plastic is the way to go if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of what kind of walkway to put back there, pavers (like brick or bluestone) could be easier to remove and put back in the future.  You also can consider putting the pavers flat with the driveway, and having a step up to the porch, or vice versa, which gives you the opportunity to deepen the porch.  A 10" slab is a lot of material to replace.